# IList<Object> to XML via a ForEach

Tags: xml, linq, foreach

I am trying to find a good example of how to do a ForEach to take a List and convert it to XML. The reason I want to do a ForEach is because I can do a try/catch on each item and make sure I process all the roads before they fail. This is really coming for a decrypted excel file on the file system, but if I can do it via a List, I think I'll be able to convert it. If it does fail, now with it being a ForEach, I now have the ability to make the XML document no matter what and also log what column fails and what row (ie what person's name it failed on). Then I can check the actual excel file and fix the issue and re-upload just that record.

Any help would be appreciate it. Eventually we are pushing this XML document via a Stored Procedure to SQL server to do the sp_xml parse to insert it into the database.

Here is how I am currently doing it, but if one thing messes up the entire file does not process etc.

```
            var xmlDoc = new XDocument(
                   new XDeclaration("1.0", "iso-8859-1", "yes"),
                   new XElement("Package",
                       from str in TheList
                       let fields = str.Split('\t')
                       select new XElement("Record",
                                           new XElement("FileId", FileData.FileId),
                                           new XElement("LineId", (lineId++).ToString())
   )
                                      )
                                 );


return xmlDoc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I was looking for. Hope it helps someone else!

```
http://forums.asp.net/p/2024939/5830279.aspx?p=True&t=635545389391660247

using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace MyTestApplication.UI.TestXMLForEach
{

```
public partial class TestXMLForEach : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    TestRepo repo = new TestRepo();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Start @" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Response.Write("<br/>"); Response.Write("<br/>");
        MakeXML();
        Response.Write("<br/>"); Response.Write("<br/>");
        Response.Write("End @" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private IList<TestXMLDTO> GetXMLInfo()
    {
        IList<TestXMLDTO> theList = new List<TestXMLDTO>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
             theList.Add(new TestXMLDTO 
             { 
                 Id = i, 
                 FirstName = string.Format("FirstName_{0}",i.ToString()),
                 LastName = string.Format("LastName_{0}", i.ToString()),
                 Department = string.Format("Department_{0}", i.ToString()), 
                 Salary = new decimal(27000 + i) 
             });

             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }

        return theList;
    }

    private void MakeXML()
    {
        IList<TestXMLDTO> theList = GetXMLInfo();

        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "iso-8859-1", "yes"));

        XElement package = new XElement("Package");

        foreach (var item in theList)
        {
            XElement record = new XElement("Record");



            XElement id = new XElement("Id", item.Id);
            record.Add(id);

            XElement firstName = new XElement("FirstName", item.FirstName);
            record.Add(firstName);

            XElement lastName = new XElement("LastName", item.LastName);
            record.Add(lastName);

            XElement department = new XElement("Department", item.Department);
            record.Add(department);

            XElement salary = new XElement("Salary", item.Salary);
            record.Add(salary);

            package.Add(record);
        }

        xmlDoc.Add(package);

        xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\XmlDocumentViaForEachAndListCSharp.xml");

    }
}

public class TestXMLDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public TestXMLDTO()
    {
        Salary = new decimal(27000);
    }
}
```

}